# How can I extract text from inside a SVG with BeaultifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the weather forecast from Google, I've managed to extract almost all of the data, except hourly temperature information, it seems like they are `<text>` tags inside a `<svg>`, I've included a couple of screenshots from the page source code.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

def get_google_forecast(region, output_units={"temp": "c", "speed": "kph"}):
    USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36"
    LANGUAGE = "en-US,en;q=0.5"
    URL = "https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&ie=UTF-8&q=weather"

    # Read data from URL
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers["User-Agent"] = USER_AGENT
    session.headers["Accept-Language"] = LANGUAGE
    session.headers["Content-Language"] = LANGUAGE
    html = session.get(f"{URL}+{region.replace(' ', '+')}")
    soup = bs(html.text, "html.parser")

    # Store data in dictionary
    data = {}
    data["region"] = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "wob_loc"}).text
    data["temp"] = float(soup.find("span", attrs={"id": "wob_tm"}).text)
    data["dayhour"] = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "wob_dts"}).text
    data["weather_now"] = soup.find("span", attrs={"id": "wob_dc"}).text
    data["precipitation"] = soup.find("span", attrs={"id": "wob_pp"}).text
    data["humidity"] = float(soup.find("span", attrs={"id": "wob_hm"}).text.replace("%", ""))
    data["wind"] = soup.find("span", attrs={"id": "wob_ws"}).text
    
    # Hourly temperatures
    temperatures = soup.find("div", attrs={"id": "wob_gs"})
    temperatures = str(temperatures.find("svg"))
    print(temperatures)
```

The code above outputs this:

```
<svg class="wob_gsvg" data-ved="2ahUKEwjSxJXimJ_xAhVnppUCHa2QAygQnaQEMAB6BAgGEAY" id="wob_gsvg" style="height:80px"></svg>
```

And I have already tried this other code:

```
temperatures = soup.find("text", attrs={"class": ["wob_t", "wob_gs_l0"]})
print(temperatures)
```

But had no luck. It returns `None`

[This is the URL](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&ie=UTF-8&q=weather%20curitiba)

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwRCB.png)
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kZQk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The temperature and other data is embedded inside the page in Javascript. You can use this example how to parse it:

```py
import re
import json
import requests


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
}
url = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&lr=lang_en&ie=UTF-8&q=weather%20curitiba"

text = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
data = re.search(r"pmc='({.*?})'", text).group(1)
data = json.loads(data.replace(r"\x22", '"').replace(r'\\"', r"\""))

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data["wobnm"]["wobhl"]:
    print(d["dts"], d["tm"], "Celsius")
```

Prints:

```
Monday 14:00 14 Celsius
Monday 15:00 14 Celsius
Monday 16:00 14 Celsius
Monday 17:00 14 Celsius
Monday 18:00 13 Celsius
Monday 19:00 13 Celsius
Monday 20:00 13 Celsius
Monday 21:00 12 Celsius
Monday 22:00 12 Celsius
Monday 23:00 12 Celsius
Tuesday 00:00 12 Celsius
Tuesday 01:00 12 Celsius

...and so on.
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need, awesome work, thank you very much!